# Java: `enum` vs `String` as Parameters

Tags: java, enums, string, constants

I've been reading through the details of the `System` libraries `set` and `get` methods yet the parameters are usually Strings.

Would you consider the use of `String` as parameters bad practise since the inclusion of `enum`?

A better alternative at minimum might be `public final String`, No?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would consider Enums to be a better approach than Strings. They are type safe and comparing them is faster than comparing Strings.

As a pre Java 1.5 alternative you could use the type-safe enum pattern suggested by Joshua Bloch in his book Effective Java. For type-safe enums see also http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html

Answer (score 20):

If your set of parameters is limited and known at compile time, use `enum`.

If your set of parameters is open and unkown at compile time, use strings.

Answer (score 7):

Just because you declare a `public final String` as something you expect to have passed into a method as a parameter, there's nothing stopping me from passing in anything I like.

Using `enum`s means that I can't create my own object to pass in, protecting both sides of the issue. The only time I can think you should be using constant Strings in lieu of enums is if you need to allow room for the user to extend your method to enable custom functionality...

Comment: @Martin: I wss thinking of comparing the inputs to the String const otherwise throwing an invalid input exception, not nice.  I asked the question because of the suggestion of open keys, this seems to reduce the WORA concept within Java.

Answer (score 4):

I've learned the "method of least surprise". Instinctively, using enum is the right thing. So i would go for it. I'm sure the Java makers think alike.

**Edit**: Excellent explanation of POLS: [http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/06/29/api-design-the-principle-of-least-surprise/](http://web.archive.org/web/20100717131330/http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/06/29/api-design-the-principle-of-least-surprise/)

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to System.setProperty(), System.getProperty(), or System.getenv(), I think Strings are appropriate here since the set of possible keys is open.  The key parameter corresponds to an actual text/string type value in some file or store somewhere.

If you have a closed set of keys, I think enums would be much preferred.

Comment: My thought on this was that an enum can have mapping details for non platform specific settings, that both should be used not just strings, and that string methods should be deprecated to encourage the adoption of enums

Comment: I think the distinction between "closed" keysets and "open" keysets is the most important factor here.  If you look at an API with dynamically loaded plugins, the plugins may contribute additional functionality which can be accessed via a String parameter, but would be more difficult with an enum.

Answer (score 4):

Although using enums is type safe, the need of converting enum to string and vice versa is quite frequent. And there is no built-in feature to do that in Java. And you'll eventually end up with using valueOf() and toString(). And using that approach will be no much different from using just strings. Because you'll need to handle situations where string can not be converted to Enum.

So just using static final strings is easy and is a common practice, AFAIK.

For example, you'll want to interact with a server using some API. You'll need to define every method and a response as Enum. And then you'll need to add toString and valueOf methods. Why just not use String?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of strings in existing APIs is not bad practice; it is bad practice to change the APIs just because Java has now support for enums. For new APIs, I agree with what everybody else said.

Comment: Overloading? Copy of my comment to lycono: "My thought on this was that an enum can have mapping details for non platform specific settings, that both should be used not just strings, and that string methods should be deprecated to encourage the adoption of enums"